# How do I setup a virtualbox server with a static ip?

Tags: ip, virtualbox, static-ip

I'm trying to get a Virtualbox instance running with a very specific networking setup.

Here's what I have right now:

I have a laptop running Ubuntu, hosting a Debian Virtualbox. My loptop regularly has dhcp addresses assigned to it's wireless card in either the `192.168.*.***` range or `10.***.***.***` range. I've set up my Debian VB with a bridged network adapter connected to my laptops's `wlan0` connection.

The Debian machine always grabs a dynamic address, so if I want to access virtual hosts running on it, or want to ssh into it, I must first run `ifconfig` to find its ip address.

Here's what I want:

I want to set up the Debian virtual machine with another network adapter on a private network between my laptop and it, that will always have a static ip, no matter what dhcp address my laptop has.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Change the virtualbox network settings to `Host-only networking` and edit the following file in the virtual machine:

```
 /etc/network/interfaces
```

You can that change it to have a static IP like this:

```
iface eth0 inet static
       address 192.168.2.10
       netmask 255.255.255.0
       network 192.168.2.0
       broadcast 192.168.2.255
       gateway 192.168.2.1
```

Then, you should change the settings for the virtual Network Adaptor in Ubuntu to also have a static IP (`192.168.2.1` in this example).

Comment: I've never heard of this virtual network adapter in ubuntu. How do I go about editing it?

Comment: Don't know by heart. Whats the result from `ifconfig`?

Comment: Hmm. I have it set up as you suggested. Virtualbox added an entry to my host so ifconfig shows the new network. However, my guest only has the loopback. If I try to add an entry for eth0 I get the error that there's no such device.

Comment: After more reading and playing with settings I finally got it. Your settings proved correct. I had used Network Adapter 2, which equates to `eth1`, not `eth0` on the host machine. Once I figure that out it was elementary to get your answer working. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

If like me, you happen to be on a Redhat based system like CentOS, just edit `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` with the following:

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.56.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

I've assigned the static IP to `eth1` but you need to change it according to what `ifconfig` tell you. To see these changes take effect restart the network service with `service network restart`.