# How to setup Android on VirtualBox with host-only adapter

Tags: networking, virtualbox, android

I am trying to setup a test environment of 2 VBox OS, one with Ubuntu, the other with Android KitKat. With Ubuntu, setting up [NAT and host-only adapter](https://superuser.com/questions/357120/how-do-i-setup-a-virtualbox-server-with-a-static-ip) is a breeze.

However, with Android, I tried 2 methods as follow:

1. First try, install KitKat with 2 adapters (Host and Host-Only Adapter) setup by default. Result is no internet connection at all.
2. Second try, install KitKat with only NAT adapter setup by default. Result is blank screen.
3. Third try, install KitKat with no network adapter, when installation complete, activate NAT adapter, then internet works, but pointer failed to appear. Also, not sure how to setup Host-Only Adapter from here.

I want to have this client/server setup to test server and client setup for android.

Comment: Because Android is not an OS that you can just "install", could you provide link to the build or guide you used? Android in general is customised by the vendor to match the hardware, so it may not react very well when your configuration is different from the build maker's.

Comment: I did not use any build guide, there are a lot of similar references if you google "setup android on VirtualBox". I'm actually posting the question here looking for that guide. BTW, this is not hardware compatibility issue. As you see, step 3, internet is working, but I just don't know how to setup host-only adapter on android, cause there is no instruction out there that one ever did to set that up. On Ubuntu, it's easy, because just a modification to the network interfaces.