# VirtualBox host-only static IP connection problems

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I’m using Virtualbox 4.3.30 and I’ve successfully set a virtual machine up with a host-only network to work on DHCP with a non-static IP, but of course, for a virtual machine server, it’s essentially useless. So now, I’m trying to set up a virtual machine Linux server with access to the internet, and a host-only static IP. Host is Windows 8.1, guest is Ubuntu server.

#### VM config

I have two network devices, one for NAT, and one host-only set to adapter #3. The NAT allows for access to the internet which works. The host-only adapter doesn’t allow the host to access the virtual machine.

#### VirtualBox config

Host-only adapter #3 has DHCP disabled, an IP of `192.168.50.101`, and a netmask of `255.255.255.0`.

#### The VM system

After running:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.50.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

…(from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/873189/cant-set-manual-ip-to-virtualbox-host-only-adapter-in-centos-6-5)) then `ifconfig` reveals that eth1 (host-only) is connected to the IP address. On the virtual machine, if I do `wget 192.168.50.101` it pulls down the default Nginx page on itself. From the host I’m able to ping the static IP address however in the browser, the IP address times out with the message `Unable to connect`.

#### Stuff I've tried!

I have also tried editing `/etc/network/interfaces` [from here](https://superuser.com/questions/357120/how-do-i-setup-a-virtualbox-server-with-a-static-ip) to no success.

What’s happening here? I’m guessing it can’t be a firewall issue as the host connects when the host-only is using DHCP and I can successfully ping from the host. It also looks like the browser's "cannot connect message" appears in the browser faster than a simple timeout.

#### Update:

I think I've hit on a bug - if I activate the DHCP in the network only adapter, and set the lower and upper to the same ip address, it seems the browser can all of a sudden allow the network to occur and succeeds.

Comment: Host os is specified, I've excluded any config for eth1 (host-only) from `/etc/network/interface` as that will only make it permanent, the eth1 up code is in the question though, and the relevant line from ifconfig is `inet addr: 192.168.50.101 Bcast 192.168.55.255 Mask 255.255.255.0`

Comment: Seriously, read the last line of the first paragraph. And like I wrote, ping can successfully ping the guest, but the browser can't reach it, though Nginx is up and succesfully running.

Comment: Not an nginx issue as I also have gogs on the server which also does not receive connections on the static ip, but does if the host-only device is set to use the dhcp wtih a different adaptor.

Comment: I'm confused myself, I can ping whatever IP address I set on the static, but the browser won't connect to either Nginx or gogs, though will on the DHCP adapter (even when only two adapters are enabled at one, the Nat and DHCP host-only, or NAT and static host-only) - it's as if the static adapter is not accepting connections, but is only responding to pings

Comment: the other adapter is bog standard nat. i've deleted the additional host-only adapter

Answer (score 0):

You state that you set the following:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.50.101 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

From all of my experience using VirtualBox, the guest OS works on a network in the `192.168.56.x` range. So I would recommend using this command instead:

```
sudo ifconfig eth1 192.168.56.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

As for why I am choosing `192.168.56.10`—instead of `192.168.56.101`—in your comment to this answer you stated:

> No, I can’t use `192.268.56.x` as the default DHCP usually works
>   within that range so will cause conflicts.

Well, the thing is with a netmask of `255.255.255.0` nothing but the last octet of the address will ever be passed to the larger network on the host. That’s what a netmask is. Further, if you look under “Preferences -> Network” from the VirtualBox application itself and then look under “Host-only Networks”, select that network—should be `vboxnet0`—and then click the edit icon and look under the DHCP server settings you will find these DHCP server settings:

- **Server Address:** `192.168.56.100`
- **Server Mask:** `255.255.255.0`
- **Lower Address Bound:** `192.168.56.101`
- **Upper Address Bound:** `192.168.56.254`

Note that DHCP is not taking up the whole range of IPs in `192.168.56.x`; it simply starts at `192.168.56.100` for the DHCP server itself and then goes from `192.168.56.101` to `192.168.56.254`. Which means IPs in the range of `192.168.56.2` to `192.168.56.99` are free for static use. Note that I left out `192.168.56.1` since that is the VirtualBox router IP address that connects the host OS to the guest OS.

And then to make the change permanent, add a network interface to `/etc/network/interfaces` like this. Open up the `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And then when all that is tested, done and working as expected you can add—or adjust—the interface details like this:

```
# The local hostmachine access interface.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: No, I can't use 192.268.56.xxx as the default DHCP usually works within that range so will cause conflicts, and this is no different to what I already have.

Comment: Nope, not working

Comment: Ping responds, on the host, ipconfig shows the network adapter and the correct ip address, on the guest, eth1 is showing the correct inet address, but it's as if windows doesn't connect the virtualbox adapter to the actual machine (so it responds to pings, but nothing else)