# Static IP for local server (VM)

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I tried a lot guides but nothing didn't really help/ worked (for) me.
What I would like  to do is to host a server in my local network with a static IP.
I have a Linux Mint VM inside Virtualbox which is configurated with a specific IP (192.168.0.30), but I don't get the specific IP (because at the moment I get a dynamic IP).
How can I edit this?
Tried Host-only-Adapter etc but it didnt't worked at all.
I also would like to have internet access with the server.
So the server hosts but can also browse the internet.

Hope somebody can help me ;)

Greets

**EDIT (to clearify):**

I have Virtualbox on my Windows 8.1 PC.

A Linux VM (Linux Mint) is running in Virtualbox.

Right now the VM network is configured as "bridged".

Works fines, I can ping the VM and I can ping my host from my VM.
(Full connection between both).

**What I want to change now:**

The VM gets sometimes another IP.
I configurated the VM with 192.168.0.30 but now the router gave me 192.168.0.20 which causes problems, because my owncloud (runs on apache) is configurated with the 192.168.0.30 adress.

I would like to give the VM a static IP adress (192.168.0.30), so that every time I start the VM the VM always gets the IP adress 192.168.0.30.

How can I do that?

What do I have to change?

**EDIT 29.11.15**

**Here the interfaces file:**

```
 # The loopback network interface
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

 # The primary network interface

 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet static
 address 192.168.0.30
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 192.168.0.1
```

VM has Internet connection (e.g. via Iceweasel) but ifconfig still tells me another IP adress (e.g. right now I got the 192.168.0.20).

Must I change some settings inside Virtualbox?
VM is right now running with bridged.

Comment: You want to have a guest in your host network and 192.168.0.30 is host network IP address? Seems like bridged networking https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged to me. If not try to expand your question a little...

Comment: Edited it, hope you understand now what I mean ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I setup a virtualbox server with a static ip?](http://superuser.com/questions/357120/how-do-i-setup-a-virtualbox-server-with-a-static-ip)

Comment: Already tried it but with host-only networking I can't work and if I change the seetings I get no connection.

Answer (score 1):

@Konstantin

Set Static IP to Linux VM (Linux Mint) is running in Virtualbox.

can you try the below process

Step 1 : take backup of the file interface
         sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces-bk

Step 2: edit the file interfaces as follows 
         sudo vi /etc/network/interfaces

```
     # The loopback network interface
       auto lo
       iface lo inet loopback

     # The primary network interface

     auto eth0
     iface eth0 inet static
     address 192.168.1.21
     netmask 255.255.255.0
     gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Step3 :  restart the network services
         sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: Tried it. Connection works (VM has access to the Internet with Iceweasel) but the IP is still another one. More Info in my post above.

Answer (score 0):

You have got two options:

- Setup your router to permanently assign `192.168.0.30` IP address from DHCP to your VM guest (probably binding of MAC address to IP address in router LAN -> DHCP configuration).
- Setup `192.168.0.30` or other IP address on your VM guest statically. Select IP outside of DHCP range, but still inside your network (`192.168.0.x` or `192.168.x.x` I guess).

In your case:

- `192.168.0.30` isn't a good candidate for static IP address - it is inside DHCP range, so select a different one outside DHCP range or adjust DHCP range.
- Keep `Bridged Adapter` settings in your VM network configuration.
- Set-up static IP address on your guest OS in a way you prefer: edit /etc/network/interfaces, or through your desktop environment GUI. You might copy mask, gateway `ifconfig` and DNS servers `cat /etc/resolv.conf` information from current dynamic NIC setup.
- Restart your network interface.

Comment: I think the first idea would be the best. However how does the second thing exactly work? I need to extract the VM later and open it on my laptop because the server should work in another network too. I would go to another place and just start the server. Is this possible? So it would be better to do the settings in a different way (no router configuration).