# How can I set a static IP address in CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, centos

I have a CentOS 7 Minimal VirtualBox VM that I would like to set a static IP address on. I want to assign the static IP address via a Bash script within the VM (so not using the VirtualBox network interface).

How can this be done?

So far I've tried editing the file : `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8`, and putting the below in it (per this question: https://superuser.com/a/365088).

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
DEVICE="enp0s8"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=192.168.100.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

But then the network adaptor doesn't restart (`service network restart`), which after a considerable amount of restarts/resets/trial, and error, and copious Google searches, it seems like it could be dozens of different things.

`ip a` lists two devices:

- `lo`
- `enp0s8`

I also have a `ifcfg-enp0s3` config file in the sysconfig dir (not sure why).

So, what's a nice, simple, predictable, reliable way of setting a static IP address in CentOS 7 minimal?

Comment: The answer you linked to is correct.

Comment: [ipcfg-en0s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003419/how-to-configure-internet-on-centos-installation-on-virtualbox)

Comment: @Ramhound - That may be the "correct" answer, but I'm afraid it's not a working answer. Sure, if I do `ip a` it reports that enp0s8 is on my new, desired IP address, and I can ping that address from the client itself, but the host machine can't access it. And as noted above, in this configuration, `service network restart` returns FAILED, although I've just got rid of that by simply deleting the ifcfg-enps03 file. I still can't externally connect to the client despite being able to on the old address before the change. (And firewalld is stopped).

Comment: Neither the answer linked nor [RHEL Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Editing_Network_Configuration_Files.html#sec-Configuring_a_Network_Interface_Using_ifcg_Files) has quoted values. Did you try your configuration without quotes?

Comment: @sebasth - the file that already exists (and thus shipped with CentOS) has quote marks. However I've tried both with and without and they make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
TYPE=Ethernet
DEVICE=enp0s8
IPADDR=192.168.100.101
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
NOZEROCONF=yes
USERCTL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

I believe your problem is primary in the missing NM_CONTROLLED=no. Except of network restart you may try to set it UP with

```
ifup enp0s8
```

You may also need to specify GATEWAY=